# Visual Studio 2019 Build menu child options not changing

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Version 16.0.2 (latest) for Xamarin Android projects but encountering a strange behaviour where options available under Build menu are not changing when I switch to Release configuration or vice versa.

Means if I open VS with Release config active then it shows options like Archive or Archive Manager under Build but switching configs (Release to Debug or Debug to Release) doesn't make any changes in options available under Build menu.

Is anyone else experiencing same and any solution to this?

**Already submitted to VS team and waiting for reply.

Update: Attached Image
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to describe where the Archive or Archive Manager is? And why  Archive or Archive Manager have to change when you switch configs?  I'm confused about your question.

Comment: Updated post with screenshot. These Archive options comes when you have Xamarin.Android project and active config selected as Release.

Comment: So, you mean when you create a new Xamarin.Android  project without doing anything, the  Archive and Archive Manager is always unavailable under Release or Debug?

Comment: Changing config from Build to Release or vice versa doesn't make any change in Build menu options. Where as Archive option should be available when I change to Release.

Comment: Well, the version of my VS2019  is also 16.0.2 and the Archive and Archive Manager is always available for me. Try these solutions to check if it works: [archive button is disabled](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/250524/after-latest-visual-studio-update-the-archive-butt.html) and [cannot-archive-xamarinandroid-projec](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/497334/cannot-archive-xamarinandroid-project.html)